# Get data from medical device : free style libre device reader by otg cable to android app

Tags: android, usbserial, medical, usb-otg

I'm working on project who the goal is to get data from medical device such as free style libre reader through otg cable from android phone. I  already have made app in order to test  android documentation about usb host (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host) and https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial but nothings when Im testing but I arrive to detect a device in my app , but I can't acces to device because I don't know device driver class to communicate with this device. I try  CDC driver class,but nothings,
Can somebody can help me?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't clear, this question is about writing software on the Android smart phone system, to accomplish the same types of tasks as the Free Style Libre Reader.

The Free Style Libre Reader is a Continuous Glucose Monitor (physical device) that reads the information from a Free Style Libre Sensor, which is a device that is glued onto a diabetic's arm, and which lasts either 10 days or 14 days (depending on the model).

There is an app on the Apple Store that also can read the Free Style Libre Sensor and software that runs on other machines. ( some information is at https://myfreestyle.ca/en/products/libre/software )

The app on the Apple Store is at:

https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/freestyle-librelink-ca/id1360453357?ls=1&mt=8

The software environments include:

• Microsoft Windows 7 (32- or 64-bit)

• Microsoft Windows 8 (32- or 64-bit)

• Microsoft Windows 10 (32- or 64-bit)

• OS X El Capitan

I didn't see anything about the Android, but I am also interested in the technology used.  I think it likely that the sensor uses blue-tooth to communicate. More information would be appreciated by me as well.

(and of course: FreeStyle, Libre, and related brand marks are trademarks of Abbott in various jurisdictions.)

Comment: My goal is to develop an android application that will retrieve the data from Free Style Reader and save it to my database via a web service. I will use the Otg cable to connect the android phone to Free Style Reader via usb. 
I don't want to use the Abbott android application because I can't manipulate the data and save it in my database.

Comment: I have already written a code that allows me to connect to Free Style Libre Reader via [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host).
But I can't reader data because the readConnection.bulkTransfer (readEp, bytes, packetSize, 3000); return -1. 
I don't know how to resolve this issue